# How to get FrontMost App is iOS8

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, xcode6, springboard

Earlier I was using spring board framework to get frontmost App it is working fine upto ios7 , but in iOS8 . I am not getting frontmost App name. I am using this code .

```
#define SBSERVPATH "/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices"
#define UIKITPATH "/System/Library/Framework/UIKit.framework/UIKit"
 //To get port
    mach_port_t *p;
    void *uikit = dlopen(UIKITPATH, RTLD_LAZY);
    int (*SBSSpringBoardServerPort)() =
    dlsym(uikit, "SBSSpringBoardServerPort");
    p = (mach_port_t *)SBSSpringBoardServerPort();
    dlclose(uikit);

void *sbserv = dlopen(SBSERVPATH, RTLD_LAZY);

void* (*SBFrontmostApplicationDisplayIdentifier)(mach_port_t* port,char * result) =
    dlsym(sbserv, "SBFrontmostApplicationDisplayIdentifier");
    //Get frontmost application
    char frontmostAppS[256];
    memset(frontmostAppS,sizeof(frontmostAppS),0);
    SBFrontmostApplicationDisplayIdentifier(p,frontmostAppS);
    NSString * frontmostApp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",frontmostAppS];
```

Can any one please help me to work it out.
or any where I have mistake , can please add a light.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you got any solution for ios 8 ?

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't. According to [this post](http://www.andreas-kurtz.de/2014/09/malicious-apps-ios8.html), getting the front most app via SBFrontmostApplicationDisplayIdentifier is considered a privacy leak and has been blocked in iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some reversing of SpringBoard and FrontBoard private frameworks, I managed to get the frontmost app of an iOS 14 (jailbroken) using `SBFrontmostApplicationDisplayIdentifier` just putting the binary inside a path like /usr/sbin

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Jailbroken environment and hooking into SpringBoard you can use SpringBoard's `_accessibilityFrontMostApplication` to get a reference to the frontmost `SBApplication`:

```
[[SpringBoard sharedApplication] _accessibilityFrontMostApplication]
```

If this returns `nil` the user is on the home screen.